Children's book with pictures of paper cutouts
I remember reading a book when I was young, but can't remember many details now. It was a book of stories, like traditional fairy stories, but they all seemed original - certainly I never saw any of the stories in other books. There were lots of pictures of beautiful paper figurines of the characters. The edition I had was one of those tall, thin books, to fit in the (quite large) photos. I think it was aimed for ages 8+ and ~30-35 pages with a small typeface.
Update - I read it around 2014, but I'm not sure if the book was new or old then. I think I remember it being published recently at the time we bought it.

Hi and welcome to LitSE. When and where did you read this book? We do not know when you were young: could be five years ago, could be 50.... Please edit your question to include these and other details that might help us identify this book. The tag wiki for identification requests has more suggestions for details to include! Thanks.
